# How can you check whether a MySQL query is making use of a Covering Index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, covering-index

How can you check whether a MySQL query is making use of a **Covering Index** and getting all the data it needs solely from that Index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an index only scan (covering index) MySQL shows 'Using index' in the Extra column.

http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/mysql/operations